# Can we delete the closed questions that were "closed as cross-site posts?"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

We have three questions that were **closed as cross-site posts**, meaning that someone posted the same question on more than one site.

- https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16078/how-does-humidity-and-temperature-affect-the-flight-path-of-a-bullet
- [Appropriate terms for activities like camping, hiking, trekking, mountaineering, wilderness survival?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14053/appropriate-terms-for-activities-like-camping-hiking-trekking-mountaineering/)
- https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16909/is-this-poison-sumac

Given that **we are never going to reopen them,** can we just **delete them**?

Sometimes I go back through and recheck to make sure we didn't close questions that should have been left open, and these just make more work for me. I also don't want someone to think that plant identification is off topic, when it is so long as you don't cross post.

Can we just delete these?

Answer (score 2):

I have removed the poison sumac one straight off - only one answer, and it has no upvotes. The cross post on Gardening is a much better placed post.

Similarly with the Physics post.

The other one is different: The appropriate term for activities - I was planning on moving it to our meta but it's really a dupe there of our post on wording so it would be closed and that would reject it right back. Probably needs deletion, but I'll wait to see what others think.

Comment: If it makes any difference Shem also answered the question about the word on english.se  so its even more of a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Unless a single user cross posted the same question [*(different discussion)*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/217279) there is no such thing a cross site duplicate. They are either in scope or out of scope, if they are inscope they should be open.

> You can't assume that all users will be on all sites. Each site has to stand on its own merits and you have to treat each site as a separate community.
>
> If a question is inappropriate on one site, users now have alternate places to go with it. It's a nice convenience if moderators choose to transfer it for them. If it turns out to be a duplicate, let the other community handle it with the means already in place. If the first moderator happens to spot it as a cross-site duplicate, it can simply be closed and the original poster can decide how to rework the question if they want to try it on another site.
>
> In the edge case where the question is appropriate on more than one site, leave it on both sites and let the users of each community benefit from the information. [Source Robert Cartaino at Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713/217279)

Comment: All 3 listed were cross posted by the same user, which is why they were closed

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh thanks for the clarification. maybe change your bold opening sentence to "closed as cross-site posts" ?